# How to test @Configuration class in Spring without starting up whole context?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, configuration

How can I test my configuration without starting the whole Spring context class or should I do that?

```
@Configuration
public class GaRuConfig {

    @Bean
    public List<GaRu> rules(){
        SSRule rule1 = new SSRule();
        CSRule rule2 = new CSRule();
        DGRule rule3 = new DGRule();
        EGRule rule4 = new EGRule();

        return List.of(rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to test this class?

Comment: Just make a unit test for your `rules()` or any other methods avail?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? That `rules()` returns the expected `List<GaRu>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [AssertJ](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-assertj) you can do the following:

```java
public class GaRuConfigTest {

    private GaRuConfig gaRuConfig = new GaRuConfig();

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnCorrectListOfRulesWhenRequested() {
        // Act
        List<GaRu> rules = this.gaRuConfig.rules();

        // Assert
        Assertions.assertThat(rules.stream().filter(rule -> SSRule.class == rule.getClass()).collect(Collectors.toList())).isNotEmpty();
        Assertions.assertThat(rules.stream().filter(rule -> CSRule.class == rule.getClass()).collect(Collectors.toList())).isNotEmpty();
        Assertions.assertThat(rules.stream().filter(rule -> DGRule.class == rule.getClass()).collect(Collectors.toList())).isNotEmpty();
        Assertions.assertThat(rules.stream().filter(rule -> EGRule.class == rule.getClass()).collect(Collectors.toList())).isNotEmpty();
        
        Assertions.assertThat(rules).hasSize(4);
        Assertions.assertThat(SSRule.class == rules.get(0).getClass()).isTrue();
        Assertions.assertThat(CSRule.class == rules.get(1).getClass()).isTrue();
        Assertions.assertThat(DGRule.class == rules.get(2).getClass()).isTrue();
        Assertions.assertThat(EGRule.class == rules.get(3).getClass()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how can I check the order of the rules?

Comment: Updated, please check it ;)

Comment: In that simple example it works to simply instanciate the Configuration class. Though as soon as you use Spring magic (`@Autowired`, `@Value`, ...) that wont be the case anymore. then I would use a @SpringBootTest with only that configuration.

Comment: Agreed, but to test only the Configuration class this is enough. Testing more than this is testing Spring Framework and not the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a Spring Context using only one (or a few) configuration classes:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {GaRuConfig.class, MyTestConfig.class})
public class GaRuConfigTest {
   @Autowired
   private List<GaRu> rules

   @Test
   public void testSomething() {
      // assertion on the rules
   }

   @TestConfiguration
   static class MyTestConfig {
     //... overwriting some beans you want to have changed for your test
   }
}
```

This will only start an ApplicationContext with that configuration class.

This is especially helpful if you want to test if your configuration in conjunction with the Spring infrastructure (which is not the case in your example). With that test you can verify that there is a bean of type `List<GaRu>` and it can be Autowired into other classes.

It is cheaper to spin up only a part of your application (in contrast to the whole application), and you can still check if this part is correctly autowired, potentially with a specific `@TestConfiguration` overwriting some beans of your productive config.

Comment: Could you please show me an example with using @TestConfiguration? Thank you for the answer by the way

Comment: Extending the example. The difference with @Configuration is that you can declare beans with the same name which overwrite your productive beans (instead of throwing an error, which would be the case for @Configuration)